# Não consigo validar cadastro com ReCaptcha usando PHP

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Estou tentando fazer uma validaçao de recaptcha em que o usuario so consegue cadastrar depois que responde corretamento o captcha. mas não estou conseguindo

**codigo Front end**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="cadastro_astral_mistico">
    <meta name="author" content="ThalisDEV">
    <meta name="keywords" content="ThalisDEV">
    <!--Captcha-->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Cadastro Astral Mistico</title>

    <!-- Icons font CSS-->
    <link href="vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Font special for pages-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="vendor/datepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Adicionando JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <!-- script para busca de CEP-->
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            function limpa_formulário_cep() {
                // Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
                $("#logradouro").val("");
                $("#bairro").val("");
                $("#localidade").val("");
                $("#uf").val("");
                $("#complemento").val("");
            }
            
            //Quando o campo cep perde o foco.
            $("#cep").blur(function() {

                //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
                var cep = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

                //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
                if (cep != "") {

                    //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
                    var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

                    //Valida o formato do CEP.
                    if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                        //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
                        $("#logradouro").val("...");
                        $("#bairro").val("...");
                        $("#localidade").val("...");
                        $("#uf").val("...");
                        $("#complemento").val("...");


                        //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
                        $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                            if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                                //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                                $("#logradouro").val(dados.logradouro);
                                $("#bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                                $("#localidade").val(dados.localidade);
                                $("#uf").val(dados.uf);
                                $("#complemento").val(dados.complemento);
                            } //end if.
                            else {
                                //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                                limpa_formulário_cep();
                                alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                            }
                        });
                    } //end if.
                    else {
                        //cep é inválido.
                        limpa_formulário_cep();
                        alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
                    }
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
                    limpa_formulário_cep();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
<!--script para formatação automatica de data-->
<script>
    function mascaraData( campo, e ){
    var kC = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    var data = campo.value;
    
    if( kC!=8 && kC!=46 )
    {
        if( data.length==2 )
        {
            campo.value = data += '/';
        }
        else if( data.length==5 )
        {
            campo.value = data += '/';
        }
        else
            campo.value = data;
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper p-t-180 p-b-100 font-poppins">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper--w780">
            <div class="card card-3">
                <div class="card-heading"></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                <p style="color: red; text-align:center;">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['CadastroLog'])){
                            echo $_SESSION['CadastroLog'];
                            unset($_SESSION['CadastroLog']);
                        }
                    ?>
                    </p>
                    <h2 class="title">Formulario de Cadastro</h2>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3" type="text" placeholder="Nome Completo" name="nome"required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="input--style-3 js-datepicker" type="datetime" placeholder="Data de Nascimento" name="data_nascimento" onkeypress="mascaraData( this, event )" required>
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar-note input-icon js-btn-calendar "></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search ">
                                <label for="genero" style="color: white;">Escolha seu Genero!</label>
                                <select name="genero" required>
                                    <option>--------------------</option>
                                    <option>Nao Binario</option>
                                    <option>Masculino</option>
                                    <option>Feminino</option>
                                    <option>Homossexual</option>
                                    <option>Transsexual</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="select-dropdown" name="genero"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 " type="email " placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input style="color: white; " class="input--style-3 " type="number" name="cpf" pattern="\d{3}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{3}-?\d{2}" placeholder="Digite seu CPF "required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input style="color: white; " class="input--style-3 " type="number" name="celular" pattern="[1-9]{2}[9][1-9]\d{7}" placeholder="Digite seu celular "required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 "type="text" placeholder="cep " id="cep" name="cep" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 "type="text" placeholder="Rua " name="logradouro" id="logradouro" required/>
                       </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 " type="text" placeholder="número" name="numero" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 " type="complemento" placeholder="complemento" name="complemento" id="complemento" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 "type="text" placeholder="bairro " id="bairro" name="bairro" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group" style="color: white;">
                        <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo_conta" value="0" required>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                        Sou Consulente
                        </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tipo_conta" value="1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                        Forneço serviços holisticos
                        </label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 " id="localidade" type="text" placeholder="Cidade " name="localidade" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 " type="text " placeholder="Usuario " name="usuario" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <input class="input--style-3 " type="password" placeholder="Senha " name="senha" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                        <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search ">
                        <label for="uf" style="color: white;">Estados</label>
                        <select name="uf" id="uf" required>
                        <option>--------------------</option>
                        <option value="AC">Acre</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                        <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                        <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                        <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                        <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                        <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                        <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                        <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                        <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                        <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                        <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                        <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                        <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                        <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                        <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                        <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                        <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                        <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                        <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                        <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                        <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                        <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="select-dropdown "></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div style="text-align: center; ">
                    <button class="btn btn--pill btn--green " type="submit " name="submit">Cadastrar</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf2YjEaAAAAAOq1D-LaAKWX5GL8TFe5tN1s5pq4"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Jquery JS-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <!-- Vendor JS-->
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js "></script>
    <script src="vendor/datepicker/moment.min.js "></script>
    <script src="vendor/datepicker/daterangepicker.js "></script>

    <!-- Main JS-->
    <script src="js/global.js "></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**codigo do back end**

```
<?php
session_start();
//DADOS DE CONEXÃO.
include("conexao.php");
//validação do captcha
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

if($captcha != ''){
    $secreto = '6Lf2YjEaAAAAAK2MIzqb_lVjMDSCqguYruWvXmcZ';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $var = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secreto&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
    $resposta = json_decode($var, true);

    if($resposta['success']){

        //opções criptografia de senha.
        $options['salt'] = '';
        $options['cost'] = 11;

        //RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO !
        $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['nome']);
        $data_nascimento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['data_nascimento']);
        $genero = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['genero']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['email']);
        $tipo_conta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['tipo_conta']);
        $cpf = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['cpf']);
        $celular = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['celular']);
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['usuario']);
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['senha']);
        $senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
        $cep = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['cep']);
        $logradouro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['logradouro']);
        $numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['numero']);
        $complemento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['complemento']);
        $bairro = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['bairro']);
        $uf = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['uf']);
        $localidade = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['email']);

        //Verificando dados duplicados.
        $sql_busca_usuario = $conexao->query("SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");
        $sql_busca_email = $conexao->query("SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");

        //comparação de dados duplicados
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_busca_usuario) > 0){
            $_SESSION['CadastroLog'] = "Esse Usuario já Existe!";
            header("Location: cadastro.php");
            exit();
        }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($sql_busca_email) > 0){
            $_SESSION['CadastroLog'] = "Esse E-mail já esta cadastrado!";
            header("Location: cadastro.php");
            exit();
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, data_nascimento, genero, email, tipo_conta, cpf, celular, usuario, senha, cep, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, uf, localidade) VALUES ";
            $sql .= "('$nome', '$data_nascimento', '$genero', '$email', '$tipo_conta', '$cpf', '$celular', '$usuario', '$senha', '$cep', '$logradouro', '$numero', '$complemento', '$bairro', '$uf', '$localidade')"; 

            if($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE){
                echo"conexão bem sucedida"; 
            }else{
                echo"Erro: " .$sql . "<br>" . $conexao ->error;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

OBS: eu coloquei os codigos em snippet porque estava saindo de formatação toda hora.
eu estou tentando nessa logica. mas se alguem souber alguma outra forma de validar o captcha estou aberto a sugestões.